# How to get the Greeter example working?

Tags: ethereum

Here is how I am starting it up

```
eth --private 9195333 --genesis-json ~/test/genesis.json --db-path ~/.ethereum_experiment -i
```

And

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]), "ether")
```

returns 6290

When trying to deploy the greeter example in the testnet, I always get "waiting to be mined". I am aware of the fact that this has been asked before and that
being the only miner I should be mining constantly and also that the difficulty in genesis block should be low. But, nothing seems to work. I tried mining all the time with the primary account being the benefactor and also used this http://jev.io/genesis_block.json as the genesis file(changed difficulty to 0x0000000 and increased gas limit) but in vain. Any help will be appreciated.

PS: A total newb here. Please point out any mistake I made. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the same thing in geth and it worked flawlessly. I guess it's an eth specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. If you use the web solidity compiler and it does not give you an output, you have to add an extra log output to actually display an error message. Check the details in my post [here](https://scbuergel.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/first-steps-in-ethereum/).

EDIT: the online compiler has been changed as of end November 2015 to include the error message even in case of an error (no, this wasnt happening before)